# Error while trying to access node mon command

Tags: javascript, node.js

PS C:\Users\पज\Desktop\Real time chatting application\nodeServer> nodemon index.js

This is the error
nodemon : File C:\Users\पज\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To enable running scripts:

Start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as Administrator" option. Only members of the Administrators group on the computer can change the execution policy.

Enable running unsigned scripts by entering:

`set-executionpolicy remotesigned`